# No puedo generar jwt en passport con laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt, passport

llevo un par de días y no encuentro la forma de generar un token jwt con [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport) y he intentado de todo, ya que esta librería no sirve, pues solo funciona hasta la versión 8: [tymon/jwt-auth](https://www.tutofox.com/laravel/jwt-laravel-8-autenticacion-con-jwt-en-laravel/?fbclid=IwAR0D5xYPugpzTL58yhR5bB42zJ5pnPrpcHYnTBLt3NPCBw2dRZGy_4JEvsQ)

he estado siguiendo un tutorial ([video de YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvI8em5Gt_8)) pero al momento de crear el jwt me sale un objeto completo y no un token.

**Codigo del metodo Login en el AuthController**

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
   
    $loginData = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'email|required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);


    if(!auth()->attempt($request->only('email','password'))){
        return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'data' => [
                'message'=>'No autorizado'
            ]
        ], 401);
    }

    $user = User::where('email', $request['email'])->FirstOrFail();
    $token = $user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;
    return response()->json([
        'status' => true,
        'data' => [
            'message'=>$token
        ]
    ]);
}
```

**y al momento de llamarlo me devuelve esta respuesta:**

```
{
"status": true,
"data": {
    "message": {
        "name": "Token Name",
        "abilities": [
            "*"
        ],
        "tokenable_id": 1,
        "tokenable_type": "App\\Models\\User",
        "updated_at": "2022-03-22T14:13:41.000000Z",
        "created_at": "2022-03-22T14:13:41.000000Z",
        "id": 6
    }
}
```

}

La pregunta mía es: ¿esta linea al momento de crear el token esta bien?

```
 $token = $user->createToken('Token Name')->accessToken;
```

¿con que método puedo generar un jwt bearer usando passport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me ha pasado, revisa que en el modelo de User o donde estes extendiendo de Authenticable el use de passport este correcto `use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;`  a veces lo coloca por defecto con `Sanctum`

Comment: Efectivamente ese era el error, aun asi despues de eso me genero otro error. asi que le ejecute `php artisan passport:install`